# How can I identify IE8 and below to post unique code?

Tags: php, html, regex, internet-explorer-8, conditional-comments

I'm intending to place some code into the header of my CMS that will alert any users who are using IE 8 and below, suggesting to upgrade their browser.

In PHP, I've got the following code, ***and it shows for ALL versions of IE***.

```
<?php
    if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-8]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        // if IE<=8
        ?>
            <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <div class="ieNotice">
                <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/images/ieUpgrade.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <style>
                .ieNotice {
                    background-color: #eee;
                    padding: 10px;
                }
            </style>
            <![endif]-->
        <?php
    }
?>
```

This SHOULD work two fold. One, the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])` should be able to tell the browsers apart. However, I'm noticing that when I run cross browser testing, IE 8 and UP are coming back with the same result for `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])`, which is:

**Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)**

OK... even if that didn't work... wouldn't the "Quirks Mode" conditional comments be there as a fallback to only show the image and link to IE8 and below?  *What am I missing here?*

#### EDIT

OK, so I have done as instructed. I have removed the PHP code, and placed the `.ieNotice` class with the `display: none` property. Now, on the stylesheet that is included here:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/css/styles-ie-lte8.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
```

I have added the following line:

```
.ieNotice { display: block !important;}
```

I have seen this work on Firefox and Chrome properly, but it is still showing the banner I've created for IE 9, 10 & 11.

Comment: Why do you even need to check the UA string? The conditional comments do the filtering for you - you don't have to worry about any other browsers or newer versions of IE seeing their contents. That's the whole point of conditional comments.

Comment: is this in the `head` or the `body`?

Comment: It WAS in the body, and it is now in the head. I've removed the UA string check.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't rely on a user agent string, that can be spoofed by users.  Especially since you are already using `<!--[if lte IE 8]>`, which will only show up on `IE <= 8`.  I'd get rid of the PHP conditional altogether.

Comment: I agree with Sam. What makes probably more sense is to change in PHP file the message (file) displayed with the conditional block for IE <= IE8 if the user agent string contains a [Windows version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions) lower NT 6.0 as it is not possible to upgrade IE on Windows XP, 2000, ... So for those operating systems it would be better to suggest switching to a different browser like Firefox, Chrome, Opera, ... still available also in newest version for the older Windows operating systems at the moment instead of confusing the visitor.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, Mofi, and I would love to do that to. Unfortunately, my hands are tied with the instructions given to me by my superiors. I've made some changes, but it's still not functioning as expected.

Answer (score 1):

> OK... even if that didn't work... wouldn't the "Quirks Mode" conditional comments be there as a fallback to only show the image and link to IE8 and below? *What am I missing here?*

You seem to be under the mistaken impression that conditional comments only work in quirks mode. They are not restricted as such; IE up to and including version 9 will honor them regardless of which document mode is in use, and IE starting from version 10 as well as every other browser will ignore them completely just like any regular HTML comment.

As mentioned, the server-side check is completely unnecessary, and can even *break* things due to the possibility of UA spoofing, so it should be removed. Your conditional comment will work by itself as designed.

Comment: Thank you BoltClock. I have made the changes but for some reason it is still showing the banner on 9, 10 & 11. I've posted my edits above.  Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

The appearance of a `<div>`, `<a>`, and `<img>` make me think that this is located in the `body` of the page. `<!--[if lte IE 8]>` should be in the `head`.

If you want to hide a `div` then make it `display:none;` by default and then use `<!--[if lte IE 8]>` an a `style` to make it `display:block` (or any other display method of your choosing) only when using IE8 or less.

Comment: Correct! So, I have made some changes, but still not experiencing what I'm hoping to experience, as IE 9, 10 & 11 are showing the banner incorrectly. I've posted my edits above.

Comment: make sure that the default stylesheet is called first before the `styles-ie-lte8.css` and it might also be useful to put an `!important` in the IE8 version, just in case. Also double check that one style has `display:none;` and the other has `display:block;` if they are both the same then nothing will happen.

Comment: You are correct! I realize I typed the wrong code here in my question, and I've made the fix. The IE8 stylesheet has `.ieNotice { display: block !important;}` as opposed to `display: none;` ... however I am still not getting the image and link to show exclusively for IE8 and below.

Comment: the default stylesheet has `.ieNotice { display: none;}` and the styles-ie-lte8.css has `.ieNotice { display: block !important;}`? and it still displays the same on all browsers?

also of note is that any form of `<!--[if IE]>` doesn't work with IE9+

Comment: The MSIE handling is as follows:

`<!--[if lt IE 7]>
 <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/css/styles-ie.css" media="all" />
 <![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/skin/frontend/default/hellowired/css/styles-ie-lte8.css" media="all" />
 <![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/ds-sleight.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->`

Comment: there is a bit of extra code at the beginning, but that shouldn't break anything. The rest looks correct. This code is AFTER the default stylesheet, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is after the stylesheet.